# No network drivers after ubuntu netinstall

Tags: networking, drivers, system-installation, atheros, centrino

After a minimal/net installation of Ubuntu 13.04 (mini.iso) both drivers for wifi and wired network are missing.

```
Wired: Atheros 8131
```

I did some research here and it seems to compile the needed driver on my own is the preferred / only solution.

```
Wifi: Centrino Advanced-N 6230
```

Since I have such a minimalistic installation, I do not even have `gcc` installed and hence it is kind of cumbersome.

Is there a way to get one of the needed drivers onto my freshly installed Ubuntu with the Live CD or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compile from source, you have two options

1. Install gcc (or build-essential), compile the driver, and then uninstall gcc if you are concerned about space, or
2. Cross compile the driver on another computer and then transfer the compiled files over.